# Transaction when using WP functions rather than vanilla SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Does WordPress provide a way of rolling back when using, for example, `update_post_meta` or `wp_insert_post`?

E.g. I'm inserting a new post and giving it some post meta inside one function:

```
some_wp_transaction_init_function();

try{
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args, true);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value');   
}catch(Exception $e){
    some_wp_rollback_function();
}

some_wp_commit_function();
```

Or do I have to use vanilla SQL, or the `$wpdb` object?

Thanks

Comment: There's no built-in function - you'll have to use `$wpdb->query( "START TRANSACTION" )` etc.

Answer (score 20):

There is no functions in wordpress to handle transactions but you can easily use the `$wpdb` object to make a simple query to achieve this. The following function will start a transaction and then insert a new user into the database and finally rollback the current transaction. In order to make the transaction permanent you would instead use `$wpdb->query('COMMIT');`

```
function test_transaction() {
  global $wpdb;

  // begin transaction
  $wpdb->query('START TRANSACTION');

  $user = array(
    'user_pass' =>  'sample_password',
    'user_login' => 'sample_login',
    'user_email' => 'sample@example.com',
    'first_name' => 'sample_firstname',
    'last_name' => 'sample_lastname',
  );
  $user_id = wp_insert_user($user);

  // roll back everything - e.g remove the new user record from the database
  $wpdb->query('ROLLBACK');
};
```

Comment: Do you need a `COMMIT` or is that assumed if no `ROLLBACK` is encountered?

Comment: You must use COMMIT: "if no ROLLBACK is encountered" is the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Note that in order to use transactions you have to disable 'autocommit' (active by default for mysql) otherwise every command is committed so the transaction has no reason to be started. In this case there will be an auto rollback of the last query in case of errors (e.g. integrity/uniqueness constraints violation, sql syntax errors...).

Comment: does it need semicolon in the end?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. You need a semicolon or whatever you use as a separator to end a statement, but since there is only one, there should be no need to a trailing semicolon in this case.

Comment: Actually @Fil, I don't think you have to explicitly disable autocommit. The MySQL doc at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html says " To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of statements, use the START TRANSACTION statement: <snip> With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state."

Comment: @scott8035, your observation is right. But the autocommit is done after each sql command. In the question there is an insert and an update. You have no way to rollback everything in case the update fails. Maybe it's ok in some case, but in general it can give you an inconsistent database. I prefer to have an error if I forget to start a transaction (the first time I run each query), and to manually specify always the end of transaction (even with only one record changed, so I have not too much cases to manage in my code :P).